# How do you attach the Scala Intellij debugger for tests?

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

What steps are needed to configure the IntelliJ debugger to attach to scala Play tests managed by sbt?

---

In IntelliJ 2019, you can attach the debugger to the sbt `run` command using the debug button in the sbt shell with no configuration changes.
However, the debugger does not attach to the `test` command.

Comment: For an example case, download the [starter project](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.7.x/play-scala-starter-example) and import into intelliJ with defaults.  Start the "Sbt Shell", enable Debugging, add some breakpoints, and run `test`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider attaching the debugger via IntelliJ's [sbt shell](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#sbt_shell_debug):

1. In the **sbt projects** tool [window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#run_sbt_scala_app) select checkbox `Use sbt shell for builds`
2. Open **sbt shell** tool window (usually found at the bottom)
3. Click `Attach debugger to sbt shell` button (the icon looks like a bug)
4. In the **status bar** it should say `Connected to the target VM` (see the image bellow)
5. Set breakpoints in your test
6. Execute `test` command in the **sbt shell** tool window
7. **Debug sbt shell** window should open and execution should stop at the first breakpoint.

[image]

---

Note if you are using Play like OP, then by default Play runs tests in [forked JVM](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.1/SBTCookbook#Fork-and-parallel-execution-in-test), so for the above technique to work try setting `Test / fork := false` in `build.sbt`.

Comment: Thanks, but in IntelliJ 2019.2 with sbt 1.2.8 (mac) this isn't working.  Before step 3, I have to click the green icon to "restart sbt shell", and that then lets you click the bug icon.  However, the shell does not show the text from step 4.  [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/MC2y4qR) of build settings and the text.

Comment: @Jethro The text from step 4 is not shown in the sbt shell. It is shown briefly in the thin status line right at the bottom of the screen. There is no need to restart sbt shell. My machine is is also mac with the same versions of Intellij and sbt.

Comment: Oops, thanks. I also had no status on the status line. Still no luck - will reinstall IntelliJ/sbt and follow the steps again incase it helps.

EDIT - Thanks for the update, I've found my "Connected" message now (:

Comment: @Jethro Status bar can be enabled by `View | Appearance | Status Bar`. There is no need to reinstall IntelliJ.

Comment: [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/3vyg8X9) - I've littered the project with breakpoints, the sbt shell says connected, but the test runs without pausing.

Comment: @Jethro Are you forking the JVM, that is, is there `Test / fork := true` in `build.sbt`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197623/discussion-between-jethro-and-mario-galic).

Comment: I managed to attach the debugger to the sbt shell, but when I execute the tests, the breakpoints are not stopping the process. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to run your SBT with `-jvm-debug [port]` like:

```
sbt -jvm-debug 5005
```

Then open dialog `Run/Debug Configuration` and click on `Remote`.
On the newly created configuration set up the correct host and port (usually `localhost` and `5005`) and click on apply.

[image: debug]

Then when you'll just need to run this configuration and set up breakpoints. After that just run `test` inside SBT console.

Comment: EDITED - This works Thanks!  
Note - If using Play Framework you must also add `Test / fork := false` to `build.sbt`.

Comment: I managed to execute the command `sbt -jvm-debug 5005` and attach the `Debug remote`, but when I execute tests with `test` the breakpoints don't stop the process. Are even to validated as working breakpoints. Any idea?